# Why videoEle.setAttribute('muted', false) not working

Tags: javascript, video

In the following, the `video` element will start off muted if I set the element's DOM property, but not if I set the corresponding HTML attribute. Why is this?

```js
const videoEle = document.getElementById('video')

videoEle.setAttribute('muted', true);
// videoEle.muted = true;
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" id="video" autoplay controls width=300 height=300/>
```

`setAttribute('muted', true)` not working

but `videoELe.muted = true` can work fine, why ?

Comment: Attributes and properties aren't (necessarily) the same thing.

Comment: could you explain for more details?

Comment: Please don't post links to your code as links can die over time. Always post your code right in your question.

Comment: My best guess is that the attribute gets read and processed upon the initial parsing of the element, but from there only the DOM property can be used to alter the muted state after parsing of the HTML has taken place.

Comment: Note that changing your HTML to `muted="false"` would have the same effect as calling `setAttribute('muted', false)`; which is to say, the video will be muted. That's because `muted` is a Boolean attribute; its functionality is determined by its presence, not its value.

Comment: This is a great question. video.setAttribute("autoplay", true) works so there is no reason for the method to fail on muted